SQLKata insert not working with VARBINARY
I have this block of code that inserts data into tables like this:
public async Task<int> InsertRowAsync(InsertRowRequest request)
{
    using var conn = _dbConnectionContext.CreateConnection(request.DbAlias);
    using var db = new QueryFactory(conn, new SqlServerCompiler());

    var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
    for (int j = 0; j < request.ColumnNames.Length; j++)
    {
        data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(request.ColumnNames[j], request.RowItems[j].ToString()));
    }
    var id = await db.Query(request.TableName).InsertGetIdAsync<int>(data);
    return id;
}

And this is the request DTO:
public class InsertRowRequest
{
    public string DbAlias { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }
    public object[] RowItems { get; set; }
}

The problem I face now is that with tables with columns of varbinary type, it fails and I have no idea if there is any way I can make it work correctly.
Given this setup (SQL Server):
create table SqlKataTable
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Doc VARBINARY(MAX) NULL,
    DocType NVARCHAR(255) NULL
)

The above method will generate a SQL script for insert such as this:
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [SqlKataTable] ([Id], [Doc], [DocType]) VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);SELECT scope_identity() as Id'
,N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(max) ,@p2 nvarchar(4000)'
,@p0=N'19751',@p1=N'asdasdasd',@p2=N'pdf'

Which fails with this error message:

Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 13
Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

The problem is that for the varbinary column it generates a @p1 nvarchar(max) which makes SQL Server fail.
Any ideas on how to make this work with varbinary types? This is basically the method behind a controller for a rest API call- so the input comes as a JSON body.

request.RowItems[j].ToString() seem to convert the data into string, but if it's binary, why not just leave it as it is?

If I remove the ToString(), I get this error for every type of request:
System.NotSupportedException: 'The member p0 of type System.Text.Json.JsonElement cannot be used as a parameter value'

Seems like it's type-guessing based on the C# inputs rather than the actual database schema. What happens if you choose a text encoding and convert your string to byte[]?

Your doc is binary but you seem to be working with json data, are you doing some sort of base64-encoding on the json side of things?

I realized that I have a design flaw. The request.RowItems[j].ToString() works with almost every sql type I've tested with so far, except for varbinary, for which I have to encode the base64 string I get from the request, into a byte[] but it will mess up the generic/dynamic added value of this API. If I change the body of the function to this (just for demonstration purposes), it will work:
public async Task<int> InsertRowAsync(InsertRowRequest request)
    {
        using var conn = _dbConnectionContext.CreateConnection(request.DbAlias);
        using var db = new QueryFactory(conn, new SqlServerCompiler());

        var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
        for (int j = 0; j < request.ColumnNames.Length; j++)
        {
            if(request.RowItems[j].ToString().Length > 150)
                data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(request.ColumnNames[j], Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.RowItems[j].ToString())));
            else
                data.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(request.ColumnNames[j], request.RowItems[j].ToString()));
        }

        var id = await db.Query(request.TableName).InsertGetIdAsync<int>(data);
        return id;
    }

Given the design, I will implement a caching mechanism for which I will cache the metadata of the authorized objects (cause I do have an authorization file implemented, to restrict and control the access to the db objects) and based on that info, I will implement the encoding for such columns.
